# Echo encoded segment of of a full json with PHP

Tags: php, json, echo

I'm setting up a simple PHP handler for my json files.

Here is my set up, I'm not sure exactly what I need to define in my PHP script to get this ID from the long list in the json.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];              //get ?id=
$jsonurl = "api/documents.json";     //json path
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);   //getting file
$decode = json_decode($json);          //decoding the json

$echome = $decode[0]->$id;           //looking for "id" within the json

$reencode = json_encode($echome)     //re-encoding this segmented json

echo($reencode);        //echo the json
```

Desired result would be

```
//load page with id set as 21
{
    "21": {
        "name": "mike",
        "active": "yes"
    }
}
```

url = www.example.com/process.php?id=21

```
// simple example of the json
{
    "20": {
        "name": "john",
        "active": "no"
    },
    "21": {
        "name": "mike",
        "active": "yes"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided some example input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$decode` isn't an array, it's an object, so you'd be better to decode it into an array and then access the keys as follows:

```
$id     = $_GET['id'];           
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

$echome = $decode[$id];
```

Notice that `true` is a second parameter accepted by `json_decode()`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Well that helped a bit.

So my code looks something like this now


$jsonurl = "api/documents.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$id     = $_GET['id'];
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

$echome = $decode[$id];


echo($echome);



However this returns a blank white page
that says       

Array

Comment: Because that's a small snippet replacement. You need to add `echo json_encode($echome);`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it as an array, decode with as an associative array by passing `true` to [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), then:

```
$echome = $decode[$id];           //looking for "id" within the json
```

or, if you want to leave it as an object, you can access the properties by doing the following:

```
$echome = $decode->{$id};           //looking for "id" within the json
```

Comment: Last example still won't work, either. May be better just to upvote my answer :P

Comment: @BenM why wouldn't the last example work? https://repl.it/repls/EnlightenedHeartfeltClasses

Comment: Because it's an array by specifying `true` in the second param. You should make it clear that there's a difference.

Comment: @BenM if you don't decode you and leave it as an object, you can still access the properties using the syntax I showed in the second example. To suggest that you can't access a object property like that is wrong.

Comment: Yes I know that. I'm suggesting you add clarity before the second snippet in your answer to show that this is the option when working with the decoded object instead.

Comment: @BenM added the clarification.